# How do I send an email to multiple recipients?

Tags: plugin-development, emails

In my plugin, I'm sending an email like this:

```
$recipients = 'person@example.com';

$email = new EmailModel();
$email->toEmail = $recipients;
$email->subject = 'My Email Subject';
$email->body    = 'My Email Body';

craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
```

Which works great! But when I'm sending to multiple people, the string would look like this...

```
$recipients = 'person1@example.com, person2@example.com';
```

... and it generates an error:

```
Invalid address: person1@example.com, person2@example.com
```

**How do I properly send an email to multiple recipients?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can loop through a list of your recipients:

```
// Comma-separated list of recipients
$recipients = 'person1@example.com, person2@example.com';

// Break out recipients into an array
$recipientList = explode( ",", $recipients );

// Create the globally known things about the EmailModel
$email = new EmailModel();
$email->subject = 'My Email Subject';
$email->body    = 'My Email Body';

// Loop through each recipient in the recipient list
foreach ( $recipientList as $recipient )
{
    try
    {
        // Add a specific recipient to the email model
        $email->toEmail = $recipient;

        // Send the email
        craft()->email->sendEmail( $email );
    }
    catch ( \Exception $e )
    {
        // Do nothing
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm a little bummed that "toEmail" is incapable of handling multiple email addresses (since the [PHP mail function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) can handle multiple recipients with no problem), but your solution did the trick as a solid workaround. Thanks Ben!

Comment: Why not use cc?

Answer (score 1):

```
$email->cc = array(
    array('email' => 'cc1@example.com', 'name' => 'Person One'),
    // ...
);
```

If you want emails recipients to see other recipients listed in the email, use 'cc'; otherwise, use the loop as the other answer suggested, or 'bcc'.